# Linear Gradient background in IE 7 - 9

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a checkbox and a Label to style, depending whether the checkbox is checked. So far I used the [selectivizr] script [1](http://selectivizr.com/) to manage `:selected` propperty working in IE7. But somehow The Gradient is not working propper in IE 7, 8 and 9. There should be a Gradient from light to darker green, but I get a deep blue gradient. I can't explain this strange behavoir, maybe it has something to do with the order of css-rules?

```
     input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
        background: #00bf00;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%); 
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 ); /* EDIT: UPDATE BELOW:*/
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00bf00', endColorstr='#009400',GradientType=0 );
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hex values are wrong for the IE6-9 part:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00bf00', endColorstr='#009400',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: thanks this solved part of my mistake, the other one was connected to it. Obviously this IE Filter shit can not handle hex values like #222, I changed it to #222222 now it works like a charme